# How do I hide a specific tag from a Shopify navigation?

Tags: html, css, tags, shopify, liquid

we are trying to hide a specific tag/filter from one of our collection pages' navigations without deleting the tag from the products themselves as we still need this tag for other functionalities.

Our theme is pretty custom and I've tried some different variations of liquid code, but to no avail.

[collection page navigation with tag needed to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l744D.png)

I've attached a screen shot highlighting the tag we need to hide from the nav.

Here is the URL to that page: https://mycuisinesolutions.com/collections/all

Here is the code which dynamically pulls in all tags for that nav:

```
{% if collection.all_tags.size > 0 %}
  <div class="tags">
      {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
      {% capture tag_slug %}{{ tag | handleize }}{% endcapture %}
      <a href="" data-filterby="{{ tag_slug }}">{{ tag }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

If anyone could be of assistance or needs more information, please let me know.

I've tried adding

```
{% unless product.tags contains 'no-quantity' %}
--tag code above--
{% endunless %}
```

but this did not work. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show exactly how / where you tried adding the `unless` code, because that seems like it should work?

Comment: @RickDavies I added the `unless` code around the tag code I listed above

Comment: Well, I suspect you did that wrong, but I can’t tell unless you show what you actually did. Can you show the combined code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to check the `product.tags` on some reason. You need to check the tag itself in the loop. The below code should work for you.

```
{% if collection.all_tags.size > 0 %}
<div class="tags">
  {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% capture tag_slug %}{{ tag | handleize }}{% endcapture %}

    {%- if tag_slug == "no-quantity" -%}
      {%- continue -%}
    {%- endif -%}

    <a href="" data-filterby="{{ tag_slug }}">{{ tag }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```